# Removing tag element from array also removes the tag behind it react antd

Tags: reactjs, antd, mobx

I'm having an issue when I delete a tag that has another tag behind it. For example if i have two ant Tags and i delete the first one, the second one disappears, but when i console.log it, the second one technically is still there. But if I have two ant Tags and I delete the second Tag first, it deletes the second Tag fine without the first Tag disappearing too.

Here is all the code that deleting Tags is associated with, I use mobx for stores, the emailTemplate.toEmail is a string formatted array containing emails seperated with ',' and in the allToEmails variable it gets split into an actual array and I put that variable in a state so I can manipulate it.

```
const allToEmails = emailTemplate && emailTemplate.toEmail ?
           emailTemplate.toEmail.replace(/ /g, '').split(",") : [];
const [ toEmails, setToEmails ] = useState(allToEmails);

useEffect(() =>{
  emailTemplate.setAttr("toEmail", toEmails.toString());
  emailTemplate.save();
},[toEmails]);

const handleRemoveTag = (value) => {
  setToEmails(toEmails.filter(email => email !== value));
};

<React.Fragment>
      {
        toEmails.map( (email, index) => {
          return (
            <EmailTag
              key={index}
              email={email}
              index={index}
              handleEmailChange={handleEmailChange}
              handleRemoveTag={handleRemoveTag}
            />
          )
        })
      }
<React.Fragment />
```

Here is the EmailTag class:

```
function EmailTag({intl: { formatMessage }, email, index, handleEmailChange, 
  handleRemoveTag, ...props}) {

  const [ isEditing, setIsEditing ] = useState(false);
  const [ emailValue, setEmailValue ] = useState(email);
  const handleEmailValueChange = (e) => setEmailValue(e.target.value);

  if (!isEditing) {
    return (
      <EmailTagLabel
        key={index}
        closable={true}
        onClose={() => handleRemoveTag(email)}
      >
        <span
          onDoubleClick={() => {
            setIsEditing(true);
          }}
        >
          {emailValue}
        </span>
      </EmailTagLabel>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <EditEmailInput
        autoFocus
        value={emailValue}
        size="small"
        onChange={handleEmailValueChange}
        onBlur={() => { handleEmailChange(emailValue, index) ? setIsEditing(false) : setIsEditing(true) }}
        onPressEnter={() => { handleEmailChange(emailValue, index) ? setIsEditing(false) : setIsEditing(true) }}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default injectIntl(observer(EmailTag))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by replacing value of key prop with something not index, index messes it up.